# How to use attribute table field name as the Output filename expression in Print composer?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer, expression

I have several features I want exported as individual images. I am using Print composer and the export process was successful, but the output shows generic filenames like `output_1.png`:

[image: Generic output filenames]

It obviously came from the default value of `'output_'||@atlas_featurenumber` under **Atlas generation** > **Output filenames expression**:

[image: Output filename expression]

I am not familiar with what expression to use. How can I make each feature's `name` column (from the layer's attribute table) as the filename of its exported image?

[image: Attribute table name field]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"name"` in the output filename expression ... maybe ? Note that avoiding spaces in file names is still a good idea.

*(With single file export unchecked of course)*

You can try the following :

```
regexp_replace("name",'[\\s\'-]','_')
```

To replace spaces, hyphens or quotes in your **name** field

Comment: Yes, sorry, haven't checked that simple expression before asking.

Comment: No problem ... i completed my answer giving an example ...

Answer (score 3):

You need to use this in the Output filename expression:

```
'Output_'|| "name"
```